# Textarea $_POST returning no value

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a textarea that posts data into a variable and then I can call that variable later to save it to database, but no matter what I try it returns nothing, either an empty string or NULL, the code looks like this

```
<textarea id="comments" name="comments" cols="30" rows="4" placeholder="Kirjoita tähän:">' . $comments = $_POST['comments'] .
            $_SESSION['commentone'] = $_POST['comments']; echo '</textarea>';
```

but for some reason if I change this up into:

```
    <textarea id="comments" name="comments" cols="30" rows="4" placeholder="Kirjoita tähän:">' . $comments = $_POST['comments'] .
    $_SESSION['commentone'] = $_POST['comments'] . "test123"; echo '</textarea>';
```

it will return "test123" no matter if I add anything after it or delete it completely from the textarea. if there's something unclear, please ask. 
small edit: added a name into the textarea

by request here is the full form code:

```
<form action="" method="POST" style="border:0px solid #ccc">
            <fieldset><legend><b>Tuotteiden palautus</b></legend>
              <div class="step">
            <legend>Askel 3/3</legend>
          </div>
          <br />
              <p class="important">Palautuksen varmistus</p>
              <br />
              <div class="valitse">
            <p class="important">Haluatko varmasti palauttaa seuraavat tuotteet?</p>
          </div>
            <hr>';
            $test = $_POST['productinfo'];
            $total2 = 0;
            for($i=0; $i < sizeof($test); $i++) {
            list($name, $quantity, $total) = explode("|", $test[$i]);
            echo "Nimi: ".$name;
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Määrä: ".$quantity;
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Hinta: ".$total . "€";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<br/>";
            $total2 += $total;
}

            $_SESSION['product'] = $name;

            echo '
            <br />
            <br />
            <h4>Kirjoita alas, miksi haluat palauttaa tuotteen/tuotteet?</h3>
            <textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="30" rows="4" placeholder="Kirjoita tähän:">' . $comments = $_POST['comments'] . $_SESSION['commentone'] = $_POST['comments']; echo '</textarea>';

            $comments = $_POST['comments'];
            echo $comments;
            echo'

            <div class="refundprice">' .
            '<label>Palautettavien tuotteiden yhteishinta: ' . $total2 . '€' . '</label>
          </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
              <input type="hidden" name="page" value="3">
              <input type="submit" class="signupbtn" name="sendrqst" value="Lähetä">
          </div>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Comment: missing: `name='xxxxx'`

Comment: Where is your name field

Comment: Because your textarea do not have a name, only name is available when you submit the form on the serverside

Comment: even when a name is defined it won't return anything else NULL/test123 if defined

Comment: is the textarea inside of the form you are using to post the information. Also is your  form set to the method "POST"?

Comment: The text area is placed within a form where the method is "POST" yes, everything else within the form sends just fine except the textarea.

Comment: While probably not related to your issue, making variable assignments in the middle of string concatenation is not necessarily very readable if you're not already familiar with the code.

Comment: @zenzelezz it was merely a futile attempt at making it work, while I do agree it's not very readable, if it had worked it would've been better than some other method that doesn't work

Comment: Do you actually input something in the textarea before submitting? As your code is now your textarea remains empty.

Comment: @kerbholz I do input text in there but does it not count anything that is written inside the area afterwards?

Comment: There is nothing written inside your textarea. `echo $comments;` is outside of the textarea. You only assign stuff inside it

Comment: @kerbholz echoing `$comments;` inside textarea does not do anything, still returns null

Comment: (Unrelated?): Opening `<h4>`, but closing `</h3>`. Also, do you maybe have another field named `comments` that is empty?

Comment: @kerbholz miniature typo, thanks for pointing out, does not affect the code in any way. no other fields under the name comments which could be empty, all mentions of "comments" is within the code shown in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code

```
<form action="" method="POST" style="border:0px solid #ccc">
        <fieldset><legend><b>Tuotteiden palautus</b></legend>
          <div class="step">
        <legend>Askel 3/3</legend>
      </div>
      <br />
          <p class="important">Palautuksen varmistus</p>
          <br />
          <div class="valitse">
        <p class="important">Haluatko varmasti palauttaa seuraavat tuotteet?</p>
      </div>
        <hr>';
        $test = $_POST['productinfo'];
        $total2 = 0;
        for($i=0; $i < sizeof($test); $i++) {
        list($name, $quantity, $total) = explode("|", $test[$i]);
        echo "Nimi: ".$name;
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Määrä: ".$quantity;
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Hinta: ".$total . "€";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<br/>";
        $total2 += $total; }

        $_SESSION['product'] = $name;

        echo '
        <br />
        <br />
        <h4>Kirjoita alas, miksi haluat palauttaa tuotteen/tuotteet?</h3>'.
        $comments = $_POST['comments'] . $_SESSION['commentone'].'
        <textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="30" rows="4" placeholder="Kirjoita tähän:">' 
        . $comments .'</textarea>';

        $komment = $_POST['comments'];
        echo $comments;
        echo'

        <div class="refundprice">' .
        '<label>Palautettavien tuotteiden yhteishinta: ' . $total2 . '€' . '</label>
      </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
          <input type="hidden" name="page" value="3">
          <input type="submit" class="signupbtn" name="sendrqst" value="Lähetä">
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: even after editing, it does not seem to post anything, only returns NULL

Comment: assign the post values to a variable like $comments = $_POST['comments'] then echo the variable $comments.

Comment: is it not already defined in the original text area code? it does go `$comments = $_POST['comments']`in there

Comment: Updated code does not work either, still returns null.

Comment: ok then you have to change the code, use echo only for php code, otherwise use the simple html and insert <?php ?> only where dynamic work is required

Comment: so it is not possible to avoid that? Since the page right now works in a way that it's a 3 part system where depending on which submit button is pressed it loads a certain page and displays using that which is why everything is inside echo.

Comment: it is possible but it makes the code difficult if you use the full page using echo

Comment: That is understandable, is there any other way to make certain elements load without actually echoing them and instead using simple html?

Comment: the best is that you should change to code to simple html and apply the php code only where necessary

Comment: I will make an attempt at that in that very case if I can make it possible.

Answer (score 0):

In the line

`<textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="30" rows="4" placeholder="Kirjoita tähän:">' . $comments = $_POST['comments'] . $_SESSION['commentone'] = $_POST['comments']; echo '</textarea>';`

you are making a couple of assignments but not actually echoing anything, so the textarea is blank.

Comment: attempted echoing using `<textarea id="comments" name="comments" cols="30" rows="4" placeholder="Kirjoita tähän:">' . $comments = $_POST['comments'] .
            $_SESSION['commentone'] = $_POST['comments']; echo $comments; echo '</textarea>';` but still returns null when posting

Comment: Same line, you are concatenating your assignments? Use <textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="30" rows="4" placeholder="Kirjoita tähän:">'; $comments = $_POST['comments']; $_SESSION['commentone'] = $_POST['comments']; echo $comments . '</textarea>';

Comment: The code you mentioned does not work either, the lines are concatenated in order to attempt to make them work by first making a variable for the post then inputting it into a session variable which is pulled later when attempting to set them into the database with the usage of another file.

Comment: When you say does not work, do you mean does not put anything in the textarea or does not produce the correct text?

Comment: Both, it does not show anything inside the text field upon loading nor does it take anything written into the text field afterward forward into the variable

Comment: I've just run it on my server and it seems to work as I would expect.

Comment: Are you running it while completely echoing the page or using simple html to run the page and adding php where needed?

Comment: Your full code above wrapped with html and php tags and an echo at the start

Comment: That is true, I forgot to mention in the original post that the entirety of this page is within an echo due to it being one page out of 3 pages this file loads upon different occasions, which is why there are a lot of echoes for html in the code if you take a closer look at it, such as the textarea itself being inside an echo for that very reason.

Comment: If this code works as expected then the other code could be the problem?

Comment: it could very well be, for some reason this last page of the code works really strangely overall, which is why I'm using Sessions to capture the data, cause for some silly reason variables that work perfectly everywhere else in the code, won't work in the last page and I cannot find an actual difference between the other pages and the last page which could cause a problem

Comment: Then this question is not the right question and you should probably post a new one with that detail in there.